# Rails 4, Carrierwave, jcrop, mobile to POST, not UPDATE

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, mobile, carrierwave, form-for, jcrop

Hoping someone can help me here - can't seem to figure this out.

I'm using Carrierwave to upload photos, and jcrop to crop. On my desktop, it works perfectly fine. I upload/create the photo, then the user crops/update the photo to the preferred size.

The WEIRD thing that happens is that when I'm on MOBILE (just mobile, not desktop/tablet), the update form_for will call POST, instead of UPDATE. But again, on desktop, everything works perfectly. Can anyone provide any help on why this behavior is happening on mobile only!?!

My code:

show.html.erb

```
<div class="container large-margin-left large-margin-right">
    <div class="jcrop"><%= image_tag @photo.photo.large, :id=>'cropbox', :class=>'img-responsive' %></div>
    <br>
    <%= form_for [@user, @photo] do |f| %>
        <% for attribute in [:crop_x, :crop_y, :crop_h, :crop_w] %>
            <%= f.text_field attribute, :id=> attribute %>
        <% end %>
        <%= f.submit "Crop", :class=>'large-font pink-bg white caps sm-space', data: { disable_with: "Cropping..." } %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

wow - hopefully this helps someone else. But, it turns out Android doesn't play well with Model validations. (i had photo validations of size and image type), and this consequently threw off jcrop.